# Plotting multiple values on same graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I need to plot 10 values to the same graph, right now all I get is a blank graph as the output.

```
hold on;
for i = 1:10
  [val1, val2, val3, val4] = myFunct(i, fileName);
  plot(val1);
end;
```

I'd like `val1` to be plotted on the same graph and so each value of `val1` link up.

Comment: you could store them all in a growing variable (e.g. `[val1(i), ...`) and then move the plot command after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick fix to your problem would be to collect all the returned values in a growing variable and move the plot command after the loop:

```
for i = 1:10

    [val1(i), val2(i), val3(i), val4(i)] = myFunct(i, fileName);

end;

plot(val1)
```

Comment: This worked. After changing plot to semilogy I'm getting a blank graph again. Why does plot work but semilogy doesn't? I should've mentioned the y log scale in the original question but I didn't realise I needed a log scale until now.

Comment: @CSStudent Did you get any warnings when you switched to log scale? If it worked on a linear scale but not log, my guess would be that you have negative or zero values.

Comment: @DavidK No warnings, I think I'll post another question regarding it. All I did was change plot to semilogy. I've never used log scales in MATLAB so I'm probably making an obvious mistake.

Comment: @CSStudent If the answer solved your question, please mark it as the correct answer.